# Como puedo filtrar los anios 2016 y 2017 en python usando pandas?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, filtro, google-colab

Básicamente tengo que sacar los promedios de cada año pero los tengo que separar por 2016 y 2017
Lo que escribí de codigo para delimitar los meses del año 2016

Data[(Data['fecha_inicio'] >= '01/01/2016') & (Data['fecha_inicio'] <= '01/10/2016') ]

con este me siguen saliendo datos que tiene 2017

tambien ya intente con .dt.year == 2016 pero me sale AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Hola, consulta, podrías agregar el dataframe completo, gracias

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Iin2VbX5z0mDhoR72LETaeLfIYvHa6W/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101214172796438242482&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d9bwp4G0wR5r4d7600fqul-wajU8G_50?usp=sharing

Comment: En realidad, la mejor opcion seria que agregases datos de ejemplo para hacer pruebas. El dataframe completo podria tener muuuuchos datos.

Comment: Buen día @AdrianSiller, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para lograrlo primero debes asegurarte que las columnas de `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_final` sean realmente fechas, por defecto son `string`

Utilizando tus datos en un archivo de Excel puedes utilizar el argumento `parse_dates` para convertir esas columnas a tipo fecha.

Por último puedes agrupar todo el `dataframe` por año y calcular el promedio de todas las columnas numéricas

Ejemplo completo utilizando tus datos en un archivo "sample.xlsx":

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_dates=['fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin'])
print(df.groupby([df['fecha_inicio'].dt.year]).mean(numeric_only = True))
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
                capacidad_base_firme    uso_base_firme  capacidad_base_firme_temporal   uso_base_firme_temporal capacidad_base_interrumpible    uso_base_interrumpible  volumetrica
fecha_inicio                            
2016            6.057602                0.036050        6.093220                        0.036050                5.960474                        0.036050                6.508091
2017            6.995503                0.040275        7.036018                        0.040275                6.966955                        0.040275                7.671734
```